Garbage collection issue (WinUI && NET8.0)
I'm currently confronted to my first GC issue. After some time of application usage (like 2minutes or sometimes 20minutes or more) the application become very very slow and the ram and cpu usage is increased significaly all at once.
At this time the GC time is significatly increased and the only one solution is to restart the application, after a long time to read some articles. This is not defintly clear, why the GC can collect like 50times in a second during the navigation in frame ? The heap size is not trigerred, easy I'm not call manually the GC.Collect.
Before the issue, the GC is alive (according the curves) but after sometime somethings was wrong but why ? And how investigate this ?
Diagnostic tools
Event during a single navigation inside frame during the issue
EDIT
Hi have tried to use the profiler in VS and dotMemory, maybe I'm not see the evident issue but I don't understand this sample things.
When the issue is present, if I tried for exemple to force the GC inside the memory profiler the GC take a LOT of time to achieve the work (and the application is in background without any interaction for a long time before and after)
A memory leak is progressive, in my case I can navigate between only two views and load and reload and repeat.
After a moment, all at once !
The GC is just extremly long, a "simple" memory leak can explain that behavior of GC ?
GC Time

Use a memory profiler. Any competent profiler should be able to list objects, sort by memory use, compare snapshots,show retention graphs etc. Large leaks are often quite easy to find and fix with good tools.

I've tried, I don't think the issue found origin from the a memory leak (the issue arrive all at once, on a view already load at multiple times).
What do you think of edit ?

I suggest you could try to test the project on another device.To rule out whether the issue is caused by system memory pressure.

The typical usage of a memory profile is to 1) Warmup the system to ensure everything normal is allocated. 2) take a snapshot. 3) Use the system in a way that should result in net zero allocations. 4. Take another snapshot. 5) compare snapshots, and sort types by delta bytes or object count. 6) Investigate anything with a significant delta. Slow GC may indicate leaking lots of very small objects, since the GC time is roughly proportional to the complexity of the object graph. A common cause is undetached event handlers.

You haven't shared enough information for us to answer your question. Possibly you have memory fragmentation due to many large object heap allocations. Possibly you are not calling dispose on some disposables. Or possibly your code is allocating a huge number of small objects (like strings) that are swamping the GC (see e.g. String vs. StringBuilder). If you could create a [mcve] as suggested in [ask] you're more likely to get a useful answer.

The application is like Chrome (with tabs, each tab has a frame, in the page some links to navigate inside the tab). I changed a lot of things in the application to better understand memory usage.
After several analyzes, the problem does not come from managed memory but from unmanaged memory. I'm not sure, GC can be slowed down from unmanaged memory?

can GC be slowed down from unmanaged memory? - It could be if you are not deterministically disposing of all your disposables via a using statement.  Disposables that directly hold unmanaged resources will have finalizers.  When not properly disposed such objects will go through the finalization process which can add extra work for the GC.

Detecting "leaked" IDisposable objects might be helpful here.

The issue was from the creation of ViewModel inside the view.
I've tried a lot of things (set to null the ItemSource of items, use Binding, remove binding, just an empty view with an empty VM, change cache mode, and lot of others things)
And the issue was here.
This is a way used in the community toolkit to do the instance of VM for a view :
public ListDetailsPage()
{
    ViewModel = App.GetService<ListDetailsViewModel>();
    InitializeComponent();
}

If you create the VM like this :
public ListDetailsPage()
{
    ViewModel = new ListDetailsViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}

The GC work properly and the view was released when the tab is removed from the TabView. I can't explain why (For the DI the VM is declared as usual).
After a lot of test with dotMemory this is the day and night, with "new VM()" everythings work like a charm, with DI for the VM, each loaded view is never released by the GC.
I'm crazy, no doubt, but the result is just evident.
